# AVCaptureSession MaximumDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avcapturesession

In my app I am recording video of up to 30 seconds. I used the following line to do this.

```
[imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30];
```

Every thing was working fine. Then I decided to move from `UIImagePickerController` to `AVCaptureSession`, It successfully changed every thing but could not set the `MaximumDuration`. Is there any parameter/workaround which can set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
CMTime maxDuration = <#Create a CMTime to represent the maximum duration#>;
aMovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
aMovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = <#An appropriate minimum given the quality of the movie format and the duration#>;
```

For further details look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

ALSO try `NSTimer` to setup camera actions

Comment: Does it stop video capturing after 30 seconds or cuts the first 30 seconds part of the video?

Comment: i didnt tried first one... i used NSTimer... make a try.. it from apple documentation.